# Why doesn't my profile picture show on my company page?

Tags: support, companies-page

My profile, answers and questions all show the same picture:

[image]

However the company page I belong to just shows a placeholder:

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: do you have the link?

Comment: Thanks @SagarV - https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/masabi

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/masabi here is a link

Comment: try the link I provided in answer to make a dev story

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you didn't enabled the Developer Story on your profile whereas the other 2 have it.

Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current

and set the Developer Story.

It will look like this[image]